# how to use onscroll gesture without lifting finger from screen

Tags: java, android

I am developing android app and I am using OnScrollGuesture on brightness increase and decrease but when I lift my finger from screen while increase decrease brightness it  works fine, but when I do not lift my finger and scroll up and down, it do not work properly Here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if(event2.getY() > event1.getY()) {
        // direction up
        increaseBrightness();
    }else {
        // direction down
        decreaseBrightness();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener has a onscroll method which is being called for scroll gesture on screen or view .

Comment: @pskink "it does not work properly" means it does not scroll properly and I have not used distance x and distance y, how can I use it without distance x and distance y?

Comment: @pskink I have no idea about distance x and distance y. How can I use with event 1 parameter and event 2 parameter for scroll up and down?

Comment: @pskink  
I/System.out: distanc X-1.0
I/System.out: distanc Y-21.0

Comment: @pskink no i have not yet .

Comment: I have used it right now but the results are

  if (event2.getY() > event1.getY()) {
            // direction down

            decreaseBrightness();
            System.out.println("distanc X" + distanceX);
            System.out.println("distanc Y" + distanceY);
        } if (event2.getY() < event1.getY()) {
            // direction up
            System.out.println("distanc X" + distanceX);
            System.out.println("distanc Y" + distanceY);
            increaseBrightness();

        }

Comment: your code worked but when it goes straight up then it won't came down...

Comment: i mean to say that when i drag it up to full the brightness, then it will not come down or decrease by the touch down

Comment: i put a condition   if (brightprogress != 255) {
            brightprogress += global;
//            setBrightness(brightprogress += 3);
            if (brightprogress == 255) {
                brightprogress = 255;

            }}

Comment: I am using methods for increase and decrease that's why i used global veriable of distanceY

Comment: @pskink it is also not working ...

Comment: no but let me show you the log

Comment: @pskink will you please show me your code maybe your code give me any idea related to my mistake please